# How can i escape pre build tests when installing my npm module?

Tags: node.js

When i install [my npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtb) globally (npm install gtb -g) on any pc it takes too slow to install, especially on windows. When i install any other module it installs way faster. The difference i see between my module and other modules is that mine executes [these tests and builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZe0z.png) for almost every dependency. Can they be skipped or are they inevitable to run? Should i set something in package.json maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These modules are not in javascript but in c++ which must be compiled against your system.
`pre-build` tests are here to ensure the package can be built on your system, basically it checks that binary/lib are present.

You can't remove it and I think the most time consuming task is compiling these c++ modules.